# Proguard - obfuscate only one class and its public methods

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I want to obfuscate a class and its public method. I am using following code to obfuscate :

```
-keep class !com.supermentor.ApiService { *; }
```

but this doesn't work. Does anyone has idea? **How to obfuscate only one class and its public methods.**

Comment: This should be working, just make sure that you set `minifyEnabled true` and it is pointing to the correct rules.pro file `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` in the app build.gradle file

Comment: @Dinash, yes it is enabled.

Comment: How you are testing whether it has obfuscated or not?

Comment: by reverse-engineering it again and again. and it shows right there without any changes it that class only.

Comment: @VipulAsri Did you solve your problem?  I am trying to tackle the same issue.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky i am not able to solve it. But I was basically looking for a way to hide my API Endpoints which I figured out a way to do so using jni.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
-keep class !com.supermentor.ApiService,** { *; }
```

But be aware order is important, firs describe what you want to exclude and then what you want to keep. In this example, you want to obfuscate `ApiService` and you want to everything else.